# For Single Player Commands, what is the full spawn list for /spawn "[name] [quantity]"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to spawn a lot of Iron Golems but don't want to make 10,000 rows of iron. How do I spawn Iron Golems using Single Player Commands?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the mob ID number, in this case VillagerGolem

> /spawn VillagerGolem 1

You can find the mob ID number on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem) page under "Network ID" in the info pane.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can find a list on the minecraft wiki here: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Block_id#Entity_IDs There are also ID lists for blocks and everything really for any other commands you want to use.  Or you could type in "/spawn list" I think.

Comment: @tugs /spawn list is ugly, but the link you provided is good too.